# Python - How to save json data output from a shell command using subprocess?

Tags: python, json, shell, subprocess

I have a shell command which produces a **nested json** response when run as a normal shell command.

However, I am now trying to run this command via Python. While doing so, I used the subprocess.checkoutput function as follows:

```
my_command = 'xyz show --format=json -j jobid'
data = subprocess.check_output(my_command, shell=True)
```

Realizing that 'data' was storing a string, I then executed this command:

```
data_as_json = json.loads(data)
```

When I try to retrieve value for a non-nested key in data_as_json, it works. However, when I try to do the same for a nested key, I am getting a key error as below:

```
billed = data_as_json['statistics']['AmountBilled']
KeyError: 'AmountBilled'
```

How can I overcome this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "nested JSON," do you mean nested *objects* or that the JSON output contains string values that are themselves JSONified data?

Comment: I meant nested objects. Example - https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+json+example&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlv4qlmpnNAhVaVWMKHfmnDQUQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=VPxuEKMtHzOH8M%3A

Comment: I suggest you print the contents of 'statistics', for example. You're receiving a KeyError, that indicates the json unpacks well (nested json -> nested dict), but something else goes amiss.

Comment: Do you see `{"statistics": {"AmountBille": "..."}}` in `print(data)`? Unrelated: for compatibility with Python 3, pass `universal_newlines=True`.